# toggling class Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a play and pause button for my video, I have trying to switch class when the button is pressed, I.e when you click on the pause button the class switches to  and vice versa.

Below is a snippet of my code of and the link to the code is also [here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/protein/)

```
$('#play-pause-btn').click(function() {
    $('#video-wall__content').get(0).paused ? 
        $('#video-wall__content').get(0).play() : $('#video-wall__content').get(0).pause();
});
```

does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: On the title of your question, are you sure it has to do with classes?  You also seem to have missed some words here "I.e when you click on the pause button the class switches to and vice versa".

Comment: `addClass` and `removeClass`?

Comment: Can you choose an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `removeClass()`, and `addClass()`...Well they do what they are named after.

http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

If you want to change the class. Try [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#td_id").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

Or [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$("#td_id").toggleClass('change_me newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/add the classes on click using `removeClass` and `addClass`.

```
$('#play-pause-btn').click(function(){
    if ($('#video-wall__content').get(0).paused) {
        $('#video-wall__content').get(0).play();
        // now playing
        $(this).removeClass("paused").addClass("playing");
    }
    else {
        $('#video-wall__content').get(0).pause();
        // now paused
        $(this).removeClass("playing").addClass("paused");
    }
 });
```

#### Addding the class when the page is opened

If you have access to the HTML, just add it to your tag:

```
<div id="play-pause-btn" class="playing> [...] </div>
```

If you can use only JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#play-pause-btn").addClass("playing");
});
```